# Crashing upon opening Blender, Python not intializing correctly, getting OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument for path to codecs.py

Tags: python, windows, installation

When I try to open Blender, I get an error relating to the file path for codecs.py, which upon investigating, seems to both be okay in terms of the file location, contents, and the filepath's format. I've tried restarting my machine, reinstalling several times, using different versions of Blender, and nothing has seemed to work. Can anyone give some advice on how to proceed? Thank you.
Error below. I am on Windows 10.

````
INFO (gpu.debug): Notification : Successfully hooked OpenGL debug callback using OpenGL 4.3
INFO (gpu.debug): Notification : Successfully hooked OpenGL debug callback using OpenGL 4.3
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\3.6\python'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\blender.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.6\\3.6\\python\\bin\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.6\\3.6\\python'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.6\\3.6\\python'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.6\\3.6\\python\\bin\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.6\\3.6\\python'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.6\\3.6\\python'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.6\\python310.zip',
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.6\\3.6\\python\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.6\\3.6\\python\\lib',
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.6\\3.6\\python\\bin',
  ]
Internal error initializing Python!
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
Switching to fully guarded memory allocator.
Blender 3.6.4
Build: 2023-09-25 23:36:11 Windows release
argv[0] = C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\\blender
argv[1] = --debug
argv[2] = --debug-gpu
argv[3] = --debug-gpu-force-workarounds
argv[4] = --python-expr
argv[5] = import bpy; bpy.ops.wm.sysinfo(filepath=r'C:\Users\ALASKA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\blender\debug_logs\blender_system_info.txt')
Read prefs: "C:\Users\Alaska Marie Keyleth\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6\config\userpref.blend"

GL: Forcing workaround usage and disabling extensions.
    OpenGL identification strings
    vendor: ATI Technologies Inc.
    renderer: AMD Radeon RX 6600 XT
    version: 4.5.0 Core Profile Context 22.20.27.09.230330

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\3.6\python\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 879, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1016, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1073, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.6\\3.6\\python\\lib\\codecs.py'

```
````

Comment: As this site is for user tips, you may want to file a bug report [here](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/new?template=.gitea/issue_template/bug.yaml&field:body=**System+Information**%0aOperating+system:+Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0+64+Bits%0aGraphics+card:%0a%0a**Blender+Version**%0aBroken:+version:+3.6.2,+branch:+blender-v3.6-release,+commit+date:+2023-08-16+16:43,+hash:+%60e53e55951e7a%60%0aWorked:+(version+that+worked)%0a%0a**Short+description**%0a%5bshort+description+of+the+error+here%5d%0a%0a**stepsto+reproduce**%0a%%5d%0a%0a&utm_source=blender-3.6.2).  Paste the above.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This is Q&A site run by volunteers, we are not programmers nor in any way associated with the Blender Foundation, decision making nor development process of the software. For bug reports please see [Where to Report a Bug](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377). If the issue is in or caused by a third party addon, please report it to the addon author instead.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted and it fixed it. I feel very silly. I previously used shutdown and then turned my computer back on, which isn't actually a full shutdown, thanks windows!